# PostgreSQL undocumented timenow() function?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11, time

Looking at the documentation of PostgreSQL I couldn't find anything on `timenow()`. Yet if I call the function it works.

So what is the difference between `now()` and `timenow()` ?

I am going to guess that `now()` is based on transaction while `timenow()` is server OS time or am I completely off?

The below is DataGrip's auto generated definition. All system functions (for example `sum`) all have `missing source code` and as you can see it's part of the `pg_catalog` schema.

[image]

Comment: didn't see any timenow function in my database. Are you sure this is not your custom (user-defined) function?

Comment: edited the question to add auto generated definition and more details. It's not a user defined function. Is it possible it's part of some sort of extension?

Comment: Yep, `returns abstime` helps a lot. (writing answer)

Comment: Maybe some extension created it? It's definitely not a "native" Postgres function: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4f65a5d7d91f826f53be7aabfcf3b56e

Comment: Well this is AWS instance, I know they're running their own fork of PostgreSQL but this is the first time I've seen a difference like this.

Comment: Also: the type `abstime` was removed in Postgres 12 (it has been declared as obsolete for quite a while)

Comment: Actually it *was* a "native" function. Try https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4f65a5d7d91f826f53be7aabfcf3b56e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is undocumented, very old, deprecated for a long time ago stuff.

The key difference from the `NOW` function is the data type of the result. `timenow` used the type `abstime`, which was less accurate and prone to the year 2038 problem. There is a small note [in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-datetime.html):

> The types abstime and reltime are lower precision types which are used internally. You are discouraged from using these types in applications; these internal types might disappear in a future release.

This type was completely removed in [postgresql 12](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=cda6a8d01d391eab45c4b3e0043a1b2b31072f5f) with all related functions. Per source code I can confirm: yes, `timenow` will return real time by every call, not the time of transaction start.

You could achieve same result by using [`clock_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) function instead of `now()`